# How can i update windows Hyper-V module on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

I have created a small RDP utility by which we can connect to Hyper-V machine on Windows Server.

This utility works perfectly fine on **`Windows Server 2012 R2`** but on **`Windows Server 2012`** display is not adjusted for full screen.

***Hyper-V Version***

- Windows Server 2012 [6.2.9200.16384]
- Windows Server 2012 R2 [6.3.9600.16384]

**How can i manually update Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012?**

*Windows Server 2012 Full Screen image*

[image: Windows Server 2012]

Comment: `How can i manually update Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012?` - Manually update it to what?

Comment: update Hyper-V [6.2.9200.16384]->to->[6.3.9200.16384] new version

Comment: what will be the best method to update Hyper-V components on current server WinServer 2012 other than to update to R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to server 2012r2 to get the newer hypervisor.

Comment: Currently we have Server 2012 as our production server so will it be possible to update Hyper-V via Service pack or any hotfix?

Comment: Hyper-v is a part of the OS, the OS must be updated in order for you to get the newer hypervisor.